# Fetching docker image and tag as key/value pairs from values.yaml in helm k8s

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I have a list of docker images which I want to pass as an environment variable to deployment.yaml

`values.yaml`

```
contributions_list:
  - image: flogo-aws
    tag: 36
  - image: flogo-awsec2
    tag: 37
  - image: flogo-awskinesis
    tag: 18
  - image: flogo-chargify
    tag: 19
```

`deployment.yaml`

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: container-image-extractor
  namespace: local-tibco-tci
  labels:
    app.cloud.tibco.com/name: container-image-extractor
spec:
  backoffLimit: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.cloud.tibco.com/name: container-image-extractor
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      restartPolicy: Never
      containers:
      - name: container-image-extractor
        image: reldocker.tibco.com/stratosphere/container-image-extractor
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        env:
        - name: SOURCE_DOCKER_IMAGE
          value: "<docker_image>:<docker_tag>"    # docker image from which contents to be copied
```

My questions are as follows.

1. Is this the correct way to pass an array of docker image and tags as an argument to deployment.yaml
2. How would I replace <docker_image> and <docker_tag> in deployment.yaml from values.yaml and incrementally job should be triggered for each docker image and tag.

Comment: What's the end result you're hoping to get?  For separate Jobs, one for each image/tag pair?  (The `values.yaml` syntax looks fine.)

Comment: I would like this k8s job to run with each and every pair of docker images and tag passed as an env [parallal /sequential execution] from values.yaml

Comment: Are you maybe instead looking for a single long-running Deployment, backed by a queue system like RabbitMQ, that you can incrementally feed tasks to?  If you need these to run sequentially, you can't do it with plain Jobs in a single Helm installation.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it, creating a job for every image in your list

```
{{- range .Values.contributions_list }}
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: "container-image-extractor-{{ .image }}-{{ .tag }}"
  namespace: local-tibco-tci
  labels:
    app.cloud.tibco.com/name: container-image-extractor
spec:
  backoffLimit: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.cloud.tibco.com/name: container-image-extractor
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      restartPolicy: Never
      containers:
      - name: container-image-extractor
        image: reldocker.tibco.com/stratosphere/container-image-extractor
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        env:
        - name: SOURCE_DOCKER_IMAGE
          value: "{{ .image }}:{{ .tag }}"    # docker image from which contents to be copied
{{ end }}
```

If you use a value outside of this contribution list (release name, env, whatever), do not forget to change the scope such         `{{ $.Values.myjob.limits.cpu | quote }}`. The `$.` is important :)

*Edit: If you don't change the name at each iteration of the loop, it will override the configuration every time. With different names, you will have multiple jobs created.*

Comment: I can visualize the expected template using helm install NAME . --dry-run. But when I am installing it, It's just picking the last one as a final template and thus running the job just for the last template.

Comment: Ah... I know ahah You need tto give your job a different name ;) Otherwise it overrides the job at each loop. I updated my answer

Comment: Although dry run looks OK. It still is creating jobs for the last image but in the loop, not overriding each other but not giving the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix a deployment.yaml as below:

```
{{- range $contribution := .Values.contributions_list }}
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: container-image-extractor
  namespace: local-tibco-tci
  labels:
    app.cloud.tibco.com/name: container-image-extractor
spec:
  backoffLimit: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.cloud.tibco.com/name: container-image-extractor
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      restartPolicy: Never
      containers:
      - name: container-image-extractor
        image: reldocker.tibco.com/stratosphere/container-image-extractor
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        env:
        - name: SOURCE_DOCKER_IMAGE
          value: "{{ $contribution.image }}:{{ $contribution.tag }}"
{{- end }}
```

If you want to know helm template syntax, you can see [this document](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/)

Comment: I can visualize the expected template using helm install NAME . --dry-run. But when I am installing it, It's just picking the last one as a final template and thus running just for last docker images as an environment variable.